# How to Create a Dynamic Property

Tags: c#, oop, .net-2.0

I have a class called TASKS.

I want one property of the class to be dynamic enough to handle a structure change in the strong type. for example....

```
Class MyClass
 {
    public [mychangingProperty] - can be any strongly typed class....
 }
```

How is this possible?

Comment: (where did `TASKS` go, btw? as in "I have a class called TASKS.")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can't be both strongly typed and dynamic; there are largely opposites.

One option here might be generics:

```
class MyClass<T> {
    public T Value {get;set;}
}
```

i.e. have a `MyClass<Foo>` and a `MyClass<Bar>` (with `Foo Value` and `Bar Value` respectively).

Other options:

- use an interface/base-class that describes the common functionality between the values
- use object and do the casting/reflection etc yourself
- use C# 4.0 and `dynamic` (not yet released...)

Answer (score 0):

probably, if I correct understand,
you want to use [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28VS.80%29.aspx)